# Api Gateway for own Auth Server and Microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, microservices, orchestration

Hi all and thank you in advance

These days I have been playing with Microservice with Spring Boot and I need some recomendation.
first I will tell you what I have done:

I have two "microservices"

1. My own Auth Server with JWT, which generate tokens based on a secretKey. This microservice returns a token if the user and pass are within the system. It also have an endpoint to register a new user by providing it username and password. This microservice manage just two entites "User" and "Rol".
2. The second "microservice" is a kind of "core" in which it owners and pets can be managed. There are a relationship between "owner" and the "user" that i will explain later. Owner entity has info like owner name, owner username, owner street, and so on.

Relation between "User" and "Owner" is OnetoOne and because the database are separated, this relation just a colum in in user as "OwnerId" and owner has "UserId".

The AuthServer also have and endpoint to set the ownerId to the userId.

The problem now is that i have to build and Api gateway that also works as an orchestrator

When the front-end app calls to register a new User, it send a generic DTO with information of both user and owner. 
The plan is that front end invoques an API gate which recives that generic DTO (user and owner info), send a rest request to Authserver sending the needed NewUserDTO(username and pass...that will be composed by the api gateway with the info received in the genericDTO) , receiving the reponse and if it is OK sending another request to the core to create the owner with the needed OwnerDTO(ownername, ownersurname,owner street...this DTO is also created by the api gateway whith the generic info) with the info returned when creating the user. 
Then if everything goes fine, it will send a last request to set the ownerId into de UserId. "I know about the cross transsaction and so on but I am asking for recommendations for this i know how to deal with them later".
The the ApiGateway must compose an response that have information of user and owner created that it is needed by the front-end (ResponseUserAndOwnerDTO).

Maybe the question is no so well explained but i have seen ApiGateways like zuul but I think it cant do what i want. 
¿What do you recomend me to do to simplify all this coding?. 
I already know that I can just code everything seting a post endpoint in the api gateway and sending the rest request for example with feing or restTemplate, but maybe there is a better solution not to have to code everything (some dependency to make it easier, or something else).
please avoid recomentations as put the owner inside authserver microservice.

Best regards and thank you.

Comment: Are you searching a tool ready to use or are you able to develop a new one?

Comment: I am asking if there is a tool for make this coding easy. I mean i have read about zuul but the articles i have ridden are just about usisng zuul as a proxy not also as an orchestrator and maybe there is something similar to simplify such things

Comment: Why breaking down systems into "Microservices" if afterwards you need "Macroservices" to bind them together again, losing all advantages of loose coupling and high cohesion at the same time?

Comment: I have never said i need a macroservice... I need an orchestrator because i dont want the front end IN SOME CASES have to call differentes services and deal with possible croos transaction issues between microservices that must to be called in some order.example:  https://dzone.com/articles/distributed-sagas-for-microservices. Some others endpoitns should be called throught the api gateway and the api gateway just will acts as a proxy, but in other cases it will orchestrate the needed request

Comment: I found this: http://progressivecoder.com/saga-pattern-implementation-with-axon-and-spring-boot-part-1/. I will make and api gateway just as proxy and then a special microservice for the request that must be orchestrated